# CSS :: child set to change color on parent hover, but changes also when hovered itself

Tags: html, css, hover, parent-child

I have an `<a>` with a `<span>` children. I have written some CSS which changes the border-color of the children when the parent is hovered, but it also changes the border-color when I hover the children, which it shouldn't.

```css
a {
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 10px solid green;
}

a:hover span {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a>
    Parent text
    <span>Child text</span>    
</a>
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

## Update

The below made sense for 2013.  However, now, I would use the `:not()` selector as described [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14792594/1911755).

---

CSS can be overwritten.

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/J4SUb/

Use this:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.parent:hover span {
  border: 10px solid red;
}

.parent span:hover {
  border: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<a class="parent">
    Parent text
    <span>Child text</span>    
</a>
```

Comment: Repeating green border on child twice, for hover and non-hover states, is a brittle workaround. What if we want NO css on child in hon-hover state? Can't do that with this method.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't care about supporting old browsers, you can use `:not()` to exclude that element:

```
.parent:hover span:not(:hover) {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vz9A9/1/**

If you *do* want to support them, the I guess you'll have to either use JavaScript or override the CSS properties again:

```
.parent span:hover {
    border: 10px solid green;
}
```