# Change font color of H2 inside div upon hover-over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the font-color of `h2` inside a `well` when hover-over. The background-color changes correctly, but at the same time I also need the font-color of h2 to change into white.
How to do this?

```css
 .well.sb:hover {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: blue;
}

.well.sb {
  background-color:green;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
 }

h2 {
  color:yellow;
}

.flag {
  background-color:#000;
  color:red;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="well sb">
       <h2>This text should change color and become white on hover-over</h2>
       <div class="flag">FLAG</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this rule:

```
.well.sb:hover h2{
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```css
.well.sb:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: blue;
}
.well.sb {
  background-color: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
h2 {
  color: yellow;
}
.flag {
  background-color: #000;
  color: red;
}

.well.sb:hover h2{
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="well sb">
  <h2>This text should change color and become white on hover-over</h2>
  <div class="flag">FLAG</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be .class > tag:pseudotag

```
.well.sb > h2:hover {
   color:white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this link for parent child hover concept:

[CSS :: child set to change color on parent hover, but changes also when hovered itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792574/css-child-set-to-change-color-on-parent-hover-but-changes-also-when-hovered)