# changing child element property on hover

Tags: html, css

I want the color of 'h1' tag to change when the mouse hovers over the 'li' tag.
I tried following the answer provided here: [CSS :: child set to change color on parent hover, but changes also when hovered itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792574/css-child-set-to-change-color-on-parent-hover-but-changes-also-when-hovered/14792701) but that hasn't worked for me.

```css
li{
  width: 100vw;
  }
li:hover{
  background-color: orange;
  }
li:hover h1:not(:hover){
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><h1>Home</h1></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry i meant h1 tag, fixed it

Answer (score 5):

In normal css:

```
li:hover h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

In scss:

```
li:hover {
    h1 {
       color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `color` property in your CSS:

```css
li {
  width: 100vw;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: blue;
}

li:hover h1:not(:hover) {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```css
li{
  width: 100vw;
  }
li:hover{
  background-color: orange;
  }
li h1:hover {
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><h1>Home</h1></li>
</ul>
```