# Button, different color for text and inline element and both should be able to change color on hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following button:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">
  TEXT<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

I would like to style the buttons text and the fa-icon with a different color. Both should be able to change the color when i hover over the button. Im able to do either of them but cant get both working at the same time:

I can style them differently:

```
.fa.fa-plus {
  color: green;
}

.btn {
  color: WHITE
}
```

This makes the text white and the icon green(Thats what i want). When i hover over the button, im now only able to change the texts color:

```
.btn:hover {
  color: BLACK;
}
```

How can i change the icons color too if the button is hovered? I would like the text for example to be black and the icon to be white when the button is hovered. But im not able to achieve the latter.

Comment: .btn:hover .fa.fa-plus {color:#fff;} ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS :: child set to change color on parent hover, but changes also when hovered itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792574/css-child-set-to-change-color-on-parent-hover-but-changes-also-when-hovered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a rule to both the button inner text as well as the icon as following:

```css
.fa.fa-plus {
  color: green;
}

.btn {
  color: WHITE
}

.btn:hover .fa,
.btn:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">
  TEXT<i class="fa fa-plus">+</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code means that you want to change button text on hover.

To do what you want, you should apply styles to your icon on button hover:

```
.btn:hover .fa.fa-plus {
  color: RED;
}
```

So, in this case, you will apply styles to `.fa.fa-plus`, but on button hover.
Hope, it makes sense to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Give a parent div for that button and add hover effect using that parent class

```
<style>
.fa.fa-plus {
  color: green;
}

.btn {
  color: WHITE
}
.hover:hover .btn, .hover:hover .fa.fa-plus{
color: BLACK;
}
</style>
<div class="hover">
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">
  TEXT<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: why add a parent div? i think its not necessary

Answer (score 0):

The below is an example of how to change the child via the parent `:hover` attribute, implement it according to how you wish to color the plus icon.

```
.btn:hover .fa.fa-plus {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to access the child element of hover:

`.btn:hover . {
  color: BLACK;
}`

Answer (score 0):

use this in each `element` one-by-one on your main page,

For an  `example`:

```
div.e:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```