# How to overwrite inline HTML style in CSS on hover in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am mapping a data and sends to the component where it passes different colors for the background of the icon. But I want to change the color when I hover on the component that is rendered.

```
``
<div className="service-card--wrapper">
    <div className="service-card">
        <div className="service__icon" style={{backgroundColor:`${service.color}`}}>
            {service.icon}
        </div>
        <div className="service__title">{service.title}</div>
        <p className="service__para">{service.paragraph}</p>
        <button className="service__btn"><FaArrowRight/></button>
    </div>
</div>
``
```

I want to change the color when it hovers on the service-card but the CSS doesn't overwrite the HTML inline-style, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: The reason it does not has to do with specificity of the CSS ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity  I would suggest you REMOVE it from the HMTL and use CSS with the class `service__icon:hover` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: Related for the parent hover => change child https://stackoverflow.com/q/14792574/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption that you want styles from a CSS declaration to override the ones in the `style` attribute, you need the CSS to have a higher specificity.  Unfortunately the only way to do that in this case (that I'm aware of) is to add `!important` to the style in the CSS (or remove the style attribute and use CSS for that as well).

Using `!important` is usually reserved for certain definite overrides or as a last resort, so if you can avoid it that would be good.  For example, if there aren't too many options for `service.color` you could have a class for each color, and then assign the corresponding classname based on the variable instead of the color directly.

Another option is to change the color programmatically in the JS in response to the corresponding mouse events.

Comment: Related reference but yes; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#inline_styles

Comment: <div className="service__container">
  {serviceInfo.map((service) => <ServicesCard service={service} key={service.id}/> )}
</div>

Cause I just made a component that passes everything and mapping it. So you think it's better to just make it one by one?

Comment: No, you could still do it that way, but maybe create a class within the ServicesCard from the service name that has the initial background color, that way all of your styling is together _and_ you won't need to do anything crazy with the specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
.service__icon:hover {
background-color: #desiredColor!important;
}
```

*Note however that both **inline style** and the use of **!important** is not considered a good practice*

Comment: I tried this the !important it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach to achieve this is to use

- onMouseOver
- onMouseOut

```js
handleMouseOver() {
  this.setState({ bgColor: service.color })
}

handleMouseOut() {
    this.setState({ bgColor: service.color2 })
}
```

```html
<div className="service-card--wrapper">
    <div className="service-card">
        <div className="service__icon" 
             onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} 
             onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut} 
             style={{backgroundColor:this.state.bgColor}}>
            {service.icon}
        </div>
        <div className="service__title">{service.title}</div>
        <p className="service__para">{service.paragraph}</p>
        <button className="service__btn"><FaArrowRight/></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work :<

Comment: Are you using class or functional component? Please update your question with the entire component

Comment: Sorry, I update my answer fixing a typo, could try again?